# Flattening Relationships in Laravel without traversal

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following Models

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function avatar()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Avatar::class, 'id', 'avatar_id');
    }
}

class Avatar extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'avatars';
}
```

I wish to get the user with the avatar information flattened as below:

```
[
  'id' => 1,
  'avatar_id' => 100,
  'avatar_url' => 'https://someavatar.com'
]
```

In SQL I can write `SELECT u.id, u.avatar_id, a.url as avatar_url FROM users u JOIN avatars a ON u.avatar_id = a.id`
Is there a "Laravel" way to do this without adding functions?
The closest I get with eager loading is:

```
[
  'id' => 1,
  'avatar' => [
    'id' => 100,
    'url' => 'https://someavatar.com'
  ]
]
```